# dotnet core 3.1 API - UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync returns InvalidToken

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

this question has been asked several times before, but none of the answers I've found have worked so far.

Here is the situation:

I am adding an email account confirmation feature to the API. The E-mail is sent and arrives successfully. However the method userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync() always returns false with the error "InvalidToken" even though when I write out the tokens when it's generated and again when it's used for confirmation they are the same.

I've tried adding a custom email token provider, adding the HttpUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlDecode methods when sending and recieveing the token, I switched from services.AddDefaultIdentity to services.AddIdentity in startup.cs class (due to most implementations I've found online being done that way), I tried using Base64UrlEncoding.

Now I've run out of ideas.

Here is the url that activates the method (token encoded using WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode):

https://localhost:5001/api/ApplicationUser/ConfirmEmail/Q2ZESjhCOElQTXRMcyt4Tm1wTzhjbXZjTGRITUVkZnN5Z3I0T0ZsQzUwU2xNWG4yQ2E5cjhIalBlWHRVK0h3aVoyT2loc1pUVXpESlo3Q2VKQTk5QXgyMDBPeHh6OHpjdkgxcU5PMHdTbFkrb05OL3Z4OS9Jc2lJdWtIbHNkMGMveXA1YXY0MjRvNzZaaFJCTldJamluWG1ZQlpRMUY4QUN5dDQrdlVCK2pudXNmSXN4QXhST3dFUmh6VDMrdldGWVBoVmlIS2s3ZWFZallxMTBNamZZdVlNcnZIc0tveVZiYitYQU5LZGRMb2JKTS8xSjNOVWlZN0FLWC92b01FSnNZRmRidz09/name.surname@gmail.com

Here is the method used to send the Email:

```
private async Task<bool> SendConfirmationEmailToken(ApplicationUser user) {


        var emailToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

        Console.WriteLine(emailToken);
        byte[] tokenGeneratedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emailToken);
        string codeEncoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(tokenGeneratedBytes);
        emailToken = codeEncoded;

        var confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "ApplicationUser", new { token = emailToken, email = user.Email }, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

        var message = new Message(new string[] { user.Email }.ToList(), "[BMC] - Confirm your E-mail adress", "Please confirm your e-mail address by clicking the following <a href=\"" + confirmationLink + "\">link</a>");

        _emailSender.SendEmail(message);

        return true;
    }
```

The method used to confirm the E-mail:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ConfirmEmail/{token}/{email}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
    {

        if (token == "" || email == "") {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var codeDecodedBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token);
        var codeDecoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codeDecodedBytes);
        token = codeDecoded;

        Console.WriteLine(token);

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        //token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound(new { isUserFound = false });
        }

        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);

        if (result.Succeeded == false)
        {
            return BadRequest(new { isTokenValid = false });
        }

        return Ok(new { isEmailConfirmed = true });
    }
```

ConfigureServices method in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<BMCContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BMCConnection")));

        //JWT Authentication
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JwtSecret"].ToString());
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "aąäábcčćdďđeęéěfghiíjklłmnńňoøóöpqrřsšśtťuúüůvwxyýzžźżAĄÄÁBCČĆDĎĐEÉĚĘFGHIÍJKLŁMNŃŇOØÓÖPQRŘSŠŚTŤUÜŮÚVWXYÝZŽŹŻ0123456789ß-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            }
        )
            . AddEntityFrameworkStores<BMCContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var emailConfig = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>();
        services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings();
        Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings").Bind(applicationSettings);
        services.AddSingleton<ApplicationSettings>(applicationSettings);


    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive testing I managed to find the error,

the error was sending the wrong data to the CreateAsync method which caused the UserManager to try to create the user twice, this in turn cause the confirmation token to be invalid as it  was generated for a completely different user.